# How to read a data input with the read system call

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'm trying to read input data with the read system call.My program should do this:

1. read to input two integer data with the read system call
2. Sum these values
3. Print to output the result with the write system call
4. Ends the program when the first input data is -1

This is my code but don't work fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>    

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {

   char buff[2];
   char buff1[2];
   char buff_w[2];

   int sum = 0, i, n = 0, val = -1, val1 = -1, n1 = 0;

   for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       buff[i] = 0;
       buff1[i] = 0;
       buff_w[i] = 0;
    }

   while((n = read(0, &buff, 1)) > 0) {
      val = atoi(buff);
      if(val == -1)
         break;
      if((n1 = read(0, &buff1, 1)) >0)
         val1 = atoi(buff1);
      if(val >= 0 && val1 >= 0) {
         sum = val + val1;
         sprintf(buff_w, "%d", sum);
         write(1, &buff_w, 1);
      }    
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a system call. Only POSIX functions. We are no debugging/consulting service. See [ask] and follow the advice.

Comment: The [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) function will return `0` on failure, not `-1`.

Comment: As for your problem, what *is* your problem? Do you get build errors? Crashes when running? Unexpected results? Please  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should be careful when using the address-of operator `&` with arrays. When you do `&buff` you get something which is of type `char (*)[2]`, not the correct thing for a string which would be `char *`. When reading or writing the arrays, don't use the address-of operator, arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element (e.g. `buff` when passed to a function is the same as `&buff[0]`).

Comment: Lastly, what if the resulting value is more than a single digit (like adding `6` and `7`)? Then your `sprintf` call will write out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: My problem is that the program don't work fine.This program should do the sum of two integer values but does not.I think this is because the second value is not read very well.

Comment: *second value is not read very well* oh dear...

Comment: anyway the resulting value must be a single digit

Answer (score 0):

Your program will not work with two read in while loop. Because in both read call you are going to read from stdin. so in first read you will get integer, but in second read you will get next line (\n) character.

For your scenario, you should read complete string in buffer like scanf, and then get integer from string, then whatever do you want do.